# How can I switch from a Tier 4 Visa to EU Pre-Settled Status in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, uk-visa, eu-citizens

I am currently resident in the UK on a Tier 4 Student Visa in a non-EU passport. I was recently granted simplified naturalisation in an EU country on the basis of my ancestry. Thus, I now hold dual nationality between an EU and non-EU country.

I would like to remain in the UK, and thus wish to switch from my current Tier 4 status (in my non-EU passport) to EU pre-settlement status (as an EU citizen).

I have failed to locate any relevant information on what needs to be done in order to accomplish this.

Do I need to inform the Home Office that I have acquired foreign EU citizenship and thus wish to cancel my current leave to remain via a Change of Circumstance Form? Or can I just go ahead and apply for Pre-Settled Status, and ask to cancel my student visa after this is granted (or will they automatically cancel it)?

Do I need to exit the UK and re-enter on my EU passport before doing this?

Comment: Note that since there are no exit checks in the UK, you could potentially just say that "hey I left via Ireland and returned with my EU passport" - likely no one would notice

Answer (score 3):

In theory the proper order of action for you is:

1. Fill out the Change of Status form (you are unlikely to get any acknowledgement that it was received so keep a copy for yourself and send it signed for)
2. Apply for pre-settled status (perhaps after you get notification that the form was signed for)

In practice the whole ordeal is a shambles and it might go wrong even though you do everything right. One thing not to do is assume that things link up at the Home Office. They do not.

Comment: The answer is quite plausible, so +1, but if you have a source to support the assertion about the theoretical order of action it would improve its credibility.

Comment: There are no sources for anything in pre-post-Brexit Britain.